# JButtonに細かいデコレーションを装飾していき、キレイなボタンを作りたい

Tags: java

**少し急ぎなので[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496865/add-decorations-to-jlabel-and-create-buttons-in-javaswing)にマルチポストさせていただいています。**

現在、`JavaSwing`でGUI開発を行っております。
そこで`getContentPane()`に追加された`JButton`で、後述する`HTML`コードのような`button`を作成していますがやり方がわからず、行き詰まっています。

---

**現在のコード：**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("TITLE");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 800);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Here");
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    button.setBackground(Color.RED);
    button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 50));

    }

  }
```

---

私の作ろうとしている実体が口では少し説明しづらいので、`HTML`を使い私が作ろうとしている物を再現してみました。以下のようなものです。

---

**HTMLコード：**

```
<div class="btn">Click Here</div>

<style>
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px #b70d0b;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .btn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .btn:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
</style>
```

実行するとこんな感じになります。以下の画像が`JavaSwing`での私の理想です。

[image: 理想btn画像]

今回の質問内容は、

- `JavaSwing`で`JButton`に`opacity`をセットすること
- `button`に`border-radius`をセットすること
- `button`にマウスがホバーしているのを`MouseEvent`で感知し、ホバー間だけ`opacity`を1にすること
- `box-shadow`を`5px`にセットし、`active`の間を`ActionListener`で感知し、ボタンが押されているような演出を作ること
- `button`にマウスがホバーしている間に`cursor:pointer`コードを再現すること

です。質問の内容が多すぎることは十分自覚していますので、答えられるところだけを答えてくれると嬉しいです。

一応質問内容のことは私なりにGoogleで調べてみましたが、どれも私の理想にしっくり来ず、ここで質問させていただきました。

---

**自分がやったこととしては以下の感じです：**

- `opacity`の件は[こちら](https://www.javadrive.jp/tutorial/jbutton/index2.html)で非透明/透明のセットの仕方がありましたが、私は`opacity`に**値を**セットしようとしているので、私の求めていたものではありませんでした。
  他にも[こちら](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/how+do+I+change+the+opacity+of+a+JButton)も見てみましたが、`setOpacity(0.5)`のように小数点で入力すると`setOpacity(double) is undefined`とエラーが出てしまいます。
- `border-radius`の件は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency)を参考にさせていただきましたが、実行しても何も起こりませんでした。おそらく私の書き方かバージョン(?)に問題があるのだと思いますが、原因を突き止めることが出来ませんでした。
- ホバーの`MouseEvent`は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393134/how-to-get-mouse-hover-event-in-java-swing)をコピーしてみましたが、バージョンが違うのか、エラーが起きてしまいました。

---

というわけで、私が質問している内容を実現するにはどの様なコードを書けば良いのでしょうか？
ご教授いただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**自己解決しました。**
[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496865/add-decorations-in-jbutton/72497080#72497080)で回答をいただき、求めているものを作ることが出来ました。

`ActionListener`で`JButton`に色々追加するには簡単な道はなく、自分で`JButton`のクラスを追加しなければいけないようでした。
また、`hover`やその他の件も`awt.Graphics`を使うことにより解決しました。